# Python can't find a module, that is imported in another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I have a project structure like this:

```
│   main.py
│
├───equations
│       resolving.py
│       resolving_methods.py
│       __init__.py
│
└───func
    │   converter.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───templates
            func_template.py
```

I'm tried to import to main.py class from func.converter and all classes from equations.resolving_methods

```
from func.converter import func_converter
from equations.resolving_methods import *
```

In this files (converter and resolving_methods) I have this lines of code:

/converter.py

```
with open('templates/new_func.py', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_f:

from templates.new_func import my_func
```

/resolving_methods:

```
from resolving import resolving
```

And python give following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'resolving'
```

But, when I try to run this files separately, code works without any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using absolute imports. Absolute imports only find *top-level modules*, while you are trying to import names that are nested inside packages.

You'll either need to specify the full package path, or use a package-relative reference, using `.`:

```
# absolute reference with package
from equations.resolving import resolving

# package relative import
from .resolving import resolving
```

See the [*Intra-package References* section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) of the Python tutorial.

Your `converter.py` module has the additional issue of trying to open a file with a relative path. The path `'templates/new_func.py'` will be resolved against whatever the *current working directory* is going to be, which could be anywhere on the computer. Use absolute paths, based on the module `__file__` parameter:

```
import os.path

HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
with open(os.path.join(HERE, 'new_func.py'), 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_f:
```